# Angular - keep scrollbar position of div when expanding child element

Tags: html, css, angular, scroll

I have a DIV container that would act as a log container in practice. This has `overflow: auto` and has the `flex-direction: column-reverse` to display the log entries from bottom to top in chronological order.

I have these log entries as a JSON structure and extract the text `line.text` of the message itself and if available another JSON structure with `line.JSON`. If a JSON structure is present, a button is displayed, with which one can show or hide a corresponding `<pre>` element in which one sees the formatted JSON code.

Now I have the problem that when I use the button to expand a log entry, the text moves upwards so that you end up at the bottom of the `<pre>` element. For useablilty reasons this is bad. This is probably due to the CSS property `column-reverse`.

[image: Gif that shows behavior]

The intended behavior would be that the scrollbar expands downwards and you don't lose the view on the button. So that visually nothing changes for the user, except that this very element unfolds towards the bottom.

I have already tried that I set the 'scrollTop' position to the height of the button but this is also a rather annoying behavior.

```TS
if(logContainer && button) {
    logContainer.scrollTop = button.offsetTop - logContainer.offsetTop; 
}
```

So my question is: How can i manipulate the scrollbar behavior to fullfill these requirements?

I have created a minimal reproduced example on Stackblitz: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhjroi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Well, that's how column-reverse is supposed to work, since it reverses anchoring points. Why don't you just use use `flex-direction: column` and reverse the order of the items before displaying them? That will save you from using some debatable workarounds.

Comment: Well yes, that would be an easy solution. But since almost all consoles are rendered chronologically from bottom to top (`flex-direction: column-reverse`), and I want to imitate a console view, it doesn`t make sense to do this differently now.

Comment: The solution I proposed achieves exactly the same thing, just without the finnicky behavior.

Comment: Oh, I actually completely overlooked that - sorry for that. Of course, that would also be a solution. However, with your solution there is the problem that the scrollbar is not scrolled all the way down by default. This would have to be solved again with scrollbar manipulation. So if I'm not wrong, please correct me if I am, there is probably no way without debatable workarounds. But I'd be more than happy if you put this proposed solution into an answer so I can better visualize it.

Comment: No worries, I've posted an answer before I saw your comment. If the goal is to start with the scrollbar at the bottom then yes, you still need to do it manually. But it's a one-off thing during initialization without any calculations instead of doing it every time.

Comment: Another thing to have in mind when deciding which route to go - `column-reverse` is terrible when it comes to a11y, since it reverses the visual order, but not logical order of elements. So you will get different results on screen readers than visual displays. Also, the sequential navigation (`tab`, `shift-tab`) will be reversed in that case compared to what you see (i.e. tab will jump to the button above instead of below) which can be counterintuitive.

Comment: Well i guess you are right. Thanks alot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, you can achieve exactly the same behavior by reversing the order of the items in the array and using `flex-direction: column`.

You can achieve this by reversing the order of the lines after you initialize them:

```
this.lines.reverse();
```

And then simply changing your styling in `.log-container` to:

```
flex-direction: column;
```

I've forked your stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b77abx) and added both solutions, you can switch them clicking the button at the top. I've added index to each line for easier following of what happens.

Comment: I was chasing the wrong rabbit ... yes this is much better indeed

Answer (score 1):

To ensure the button will remain at the same point relative to the container even if the content grows/shrinks, you need to grab its `offsetTop` before the change gets rendered and later find the difference with its `offsetTop` after the content changed.

`setTimeout()` will make sure the UI will be redrawn before running the passed callback.

That way you will have a correct difference to apply to the container `scrollTop`.

Just change this function in your code and you'll see the new behaviour with the mouse still hovering the button in both cases when you expand/collapse a node:

```
toggleJsonDisplay(index: number) {
    const logContainer = this.logContainer.nativeElement;
    const button = document.getElementById(`jsonDisplayButton${index}`);

    const originalOffsetTop = button.offsetTop;
    const originalDistanceFromViewport =
        originalOffsetTop - logContainer.scrollTop;

    this.showJsonMap[index] = !this.showJsonMap[index];

    setTimeout(() => {
        logContainer.scrollTop = button.offsetTop - originalDistanceFromViewport;
    });
}
```

Plus if you add the following styling it will be easier to understand what's going on because each button will have an index on top that you can see to understand the scrolling is working correctly:

```
.log-container {
  counter-reset: buttonCounter;
}

.log-container button:before {
  counter-increment: buttonCounter;
  content: counter(buttonCounter);
  position: absolute;
  top: -2em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: solid 2px red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.log-container button {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: It works great with expanding, but when collapsing it jumps to the bottom of the div container. For the second button (from bottom to top), it works fine, but not for the rest ...

Comment: ok I think I should readd the condition u used to discern when it's collapsing/expanding so that the scrolltop feature will be performed only in one of those cases. I was sure I checked but I see now the issue you raised in the comment. Unfortunately I may not have time right in this moment. I may come later if you didn't solve it yet

Comment: I tried quickly to make the distinction.. is not perfect enough.. I need to think about it deeper later. I hope you'll solve it anyway before

Comment: Thank you for your time, im trying my best to find it on my own. If i won't update you with a working example, i probably didn't find it yet.

Comment: changed the code using a different approach.. now it works in any scenario .. also expanding a node, the expanding another node and when going back and collapsing the previous one, the scrolltop is updated correctly